# Magento All Product Export dataflow error

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, error, export, dataflow

I am trying to export products in Magento 1.9.1 using dataflow profiles, but it stops at "Warning: Please do not close the window during importing/exporting data".

This is the error I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno::setAttribute()` in
>   app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php
>   on line 389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for hours I found the solution.

look in your database table `eav_attribute` and search for attributes with `source_model = adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno`

Then replace it with a correct source model: `eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean`

I found the solution [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Product-Export-Error/td-p/19438)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you ever face the issue, no valid send data error during products export?